# How to disable dot emmet intellisense for JS files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet, vscode-snippets

I want to use emmet in a Javascript file that contains JSX code but I don't want IntelliSense to suggest an emmet whenever I use the dot (`.`) operator.

For example, I don't want the `.rap` emmet suggestion to show up:

[image]

I tried these settings:

```
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom",
```

However, I get another problem:

[image: this problem]

Replacing `"editor.snippetSuggestions"` from `"bottom"` to `"inline"` also doesn't help.

Comment: Hey @Cvai can you mark my provided answer as real selected answer for this question.?
I think thats actually what u wanted as real solution to your problem.

Comment: @SahilRajput, what do you mean by "as real selected answer"? I accepted your answer a long time ago (May 2).

Comment: Cvai, I think I was not aware of that. I thought if it were accepted it should be on top of other answer.

I wasn't aware of it before. Thanks for telling me Cvai.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @cikamoto, I use Neovim right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way i use emmet is, I have set a **hotkey** for **emmet exapansion** as **`ctrl+e`** and use that to expand in js/ts files.

And set emmet's settings like that -

```json
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly",
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

as, this will not show emmet abbreviation(intellisense) **in other than css and html files,** and thus don't clutter other intellisense in js and ts files.

Thanks.

Comment: What about jsx and tsx files? There it makes sense to show

Comment: I think getting emmet in JSX and TSX files would simply duplicate this problem i.e., most people don't want to have suggestions for emmet. For me, it's muscle memory now and I don't feel need to see the suggestions for emmet.

Comment: I was actually thinking about tag auto-closing, but this might not be what this post is about, not sure.

Comment: you dont need to do tag autoclosing I mean simply: div<TAB> makes it <div></div>.

or say MyComp<TAB> will make ie <MyComp></MyComp>, I guess thats what you need? I have my vscode settings @ https://github.com/sahilrajput03/config/blob/main/.config/Code/User/settings.json

if you wanna see my config for different options.

Answer (score 1):

To disable emmet (that 'dot snippet' in your screenshot is one of the things emmet does) in javascript/react files you could try adding this to your settings.json file:

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [
        "javascriptreact",
        "javascript"
    ]
```

Comment: No, on the contrary, I specifically included them. I've written about it in my first sentence. I like use emmet in js/react files for jsx.

Comment: So I don't understand your question. In your screenshot the dot is emmet, the rest is not. I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to keep emmet and at the same time make it so that its suggestions was below. I tried to do it but how you can see on the second screenshot in the result I got that all my suggestions were deep below. Maybe there is some possible way to separate emmet from other and to lower only them.